# Is there a version of Ruby's Regexp.match that responds to the order of the matches within the string?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to use regexes to check if a given string is composed of certain substrings.

For example, given the regular expression

```
> regex = /(?:(foo)|(bar)|(baz))*/
```

I can determine whether a given string matches the pattern:

```
> regex === "bazbar"
=> true
> regex === "qux"
=> false
```

But I want to know how to break the string into substrings. I can almost do this with

```
> regex.match("barbazfoo").captures
=> ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

But here they appear in the order in which I specified them within the regex. I want to return

```
 ["bar", "baz", "foo"]
```

In the order in which they appeared in the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/String.html#method-i-scan) with a modified regular expression:

```
regex = /foo|bar|baz/
"barbazfoo".scan(regex)
# => ["bar", "baz", "foo"]
```

**UPDATE** according to OP's comment.

If some of the strings I'm using are substrings of the others, you need to order the so that all the substrings go last.

```
"barfoo".scan(/ba|bar|foo/)  # without ordering
# => ["ba", "foo"]

words = ['ba', 'bar', 'foo']
pattern = words.map { |word| Regexp.escape(word) }.sort_by { |x| -x.size }.join('|')
"barfoo".scan(Regexp.new(pattern))
# => ["bar", "foo"]
```

Comment: This is a much better way. (+1)

Comment: @falsetru That's really odd. I could have sworn I commented what was wrong, but it's gone now. The problem is that some of the strings I'm using are substrings of the others, so `"barfoo".scan(/ba|bar|foo/)` returns `["ba", "foo"]`. When I order the regex so that all the substrings go last, it skips over certain letters.

Comment: @EMBLEM, Thank you for the feedback. I updated the answer accordingly. Please check it out.

Comment: @falsetru This still doesn't work for me, but it is the best answer.

Comment: @EMBLEM, http://asciinema.org/a/12157 . Could you show me the example that does not work?