# How do I override the match behaviour in String.scan and FindAllString?

Tags: ruby, regex, go

I want to determine whether a given string can be created by joining any of a set of substrings. As a specific example, I want to split a string `"sgene"` according to what part of the regex `sg|ge|ne|n|s` it matches. The answer is `"s"`, `"ge"`, `"ne"`, because those three parts are how the string can be decomposed into parts from the regex, the desired set of substrings.

Go has `regexp.(*Regexp).FindAllString`, and Ruby has `Regexp.scan` to do this. In my code, one match is lost regardless of whether I order the substrings before or after the superstrings since my regexes overlap.

---

Here is a program to reproduce the problem in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    str := "sgene"
    superBeforeSub := regexp.MustCompile("sg|ge|ne|n|s")
    subBeforeSuper := regexp.MustCompile("n|s|sg|ge|ne")
    regexes := []*regexp.Regexp{superBeforeSub, subBeforeSuper}
    for _, rgx := range regexes {
        fmt.Println(rgx.MatchString(str), rgx.FindAllString(str, -1))
    }
}
```

This program outputs:

```
true [sg ne]
true [s ge n]
```

---

And here is the same program in Ruby (problem for Ruby is also seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819437)):

```
str = "sgene"
regexes = [/sg|ge|ne|n|s/, /n|s|sg|ge|ne/] 
regexes.each do |regex|
  puts "%s %s" % [(regex === str).to_s, str.scan(regex).inspect]
end
```

It outputs:

```
true ["sg", "ne"]
true ["s", "ge", "n"]
```

---

The regex engines are aware that the string can be matched by the regex, but `FindAllString` and `scan` do not match it the way the boolean match does. They seem to use a greedy longest match search that ignores at least one e. How can I use regex to split the string into `[s ge ne]` in either language?

Comment: Person who voted to close, it is not at all unclear what I am asking. I put a lot of effort into this question and it's clear that I want to split the string into `[s ge ne]` but neither language is providing that ability.

Comment: I don't fully understand the rules that you want to apply to your split operation. Can you give some more samples? 
What is the purpose?

Comment: @pascalbetz The string consists of `s`, followed by `ge`, followed by `ne`, all of which are parts of the regex. The boolean matches know this, yet the array matches do not decompose the string into those parts. I want to split the string by its regex-matching parts. Say, if I had a string "sgen", I would expect `[s, ge, n]`, because these are all parts of the regex. Or from `genes` I would expect `[ge, ne, s]`, because `ge`, `ne`, and `s` are parts of the regex. The purpose is to determine whether a given string can be created by joining together any of several possible substrings.

Comment: @EMBLEM Your initial assumption is wrong. Your regexp `"sg|ge|ne|n|s"` means any of the strings, but not the repetition of those strings to cover the whole string. So in Go `Regexp.Match()` will return `true` if the word contains any of those, even if the whole word is NOT a combination of those, e.g. testing the word `"sgenex"` will be `true` by `Match()` but you would expect `false`. To check if the whole word is a combination of such substrings, use a regexp like `"^(sg|ge|ne|n|s)+$"`.

Comment: The issue with the regex is that `sg|ge|ne|n|s` will match `sg` in `sgene` before it even tests `s`. After  `sg` is matched, the index goes after `sg` and the engine CANNOT start looking one letter before the previous match end position - this is not possible with `scan` or `findallstring`. That is why `ne` is not matched, as the engine sees `en` (after matching `sg`) and it is no match, so the engine advances its index and tests the position after `e` and as `ne` is before `n` in the regex, the engine matches `ne` (what comes first in alternation)(see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cI6hY2/1)).

Comment: @icza You should have tested your brilliant "OP is an idiot" answer. If I do that, then the string will not be split into the parts  by the methods from either language. The regex will match the entire string, yes, but I will not be able to decompose the string into its substrings.

Comment: @EMBLEM You should remain polite as I wasn't offensive. Don't exaggerate. I only posted a comment and not an answer. The regexp I suggested is only to check if the whole word is a composite of the substrings. I never said it can be used to break the word into substrings (else it would've been posted as an answer). You were claiming that your original regexp can be used to test this using `Regexp.Match()` which is incorrect, and I did test this.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Please do not treat me like an idiot who doesn't know the rules of this site. I will accept an answer when I am satisfied with one.

Comment: Neither I nor @icza think you're an idiot. The fact is, for vast numbers of questions posted on SO, no answer is ever selected, even when excellent answers are offered. True, the OP may not be ready to make a selection or is dissatisfied with all the answers, but more often it is because he or she does not realize an answer can be selected or simply forgets to select one. I therefoe see nothing wrong with a gentle comment to consider making a selection if none has been made after a day or three. I am not talking about a request for the OP to select one's own answer, which I detest.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That the suggestion of being fair perturbed you, a renowned C++ expert who had already declared that he would stop responding, enough to look into my comment history to find this example of me fighting against the very unfairness I loathe is victory enough for me.

Comment: I'm glad you feel that you can claim "victory". Myself, I'm a grown-up and therefore see no contest here. But each to their own. Although, to continue the theme of pointing out your logical absurdities, I said I would stop responding _on that thread_. I never committed to never talking to you ever again. Though you'll be glad to hear that I am now considering it...!

Answer (score 0):

This answer concerns Ruby only.

We are given the regex

```
r = /sg|ge|ne|n|s/
```

For this regex,

```
"sgene".scan r
  #=> ["sg", "ne"]
```

As I understand, you want to find a rearrangement of the order of the elements of the regex, `r_new`, such that

```
"sgene".scan(r_new).join == "sgene"
```

Viewed differently, but equivalently, you are given an array and a string

```
arr = ["sg", "ge", "ne", "n", "s"]
target = "sgene"
```

and want to determine if there is a permutation of some or all of the elements of `arr`, `perm`, such that

```
target == perm.join
```

and are asking if this can be done using a regex. I don't believe it can, but I cannot prove that. Moreover, several of the comments cast doubt on that.

It can be done, however, as follows.

```
(1..arr.size).each_with_object([]) { |n, perms|
  arr.permutation(n).each  { |p| perms << p if p.join==target } }
  #=> [["s", "ge", "ne"]]
```

I used `select`, rather than `any?`, so that all permutations that work are identified. For example:

```
arr = ["sg", "ge", "ne", "n", "s", "e"]
(1..arr.size).each_with_object([]) { |n, perms|
  arr.permutation(n).each  { |p| perms << p if p.join==target } }
  #=> [["sg", "e", "ne"], ["s", "ge", "ne"], ["s", "ge", "n", "e"]]
```

Comment: This is an okay answer, but doesn't work in Go. And it's less efficient than regexes.

Comment: You said Ruby *or* Go. If this can't be coded in Go (which I find surprising), that cannot be considered a weakness of the solution. It's only less efficient than a regex if it's possible to do this with a regex, something that has not been established.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding what you are actually trying to do, but simply changing the order of the symbols in the regex works.
This isn't a greedy vs non-greedy thing as you are using no wildcards.

It's simply a match in order of regex problem.

Here's a modified version [on Play](https://play.golang.org/p/raYWzNiFcq).  The only different thing being to change the regex itself to give you the desired output.

All I did was move "n" to the end of the pattern, as in `s|sg|ge|ne|n`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    str := "sgene"
    superBeforeSub := regexp.MustCompile("sg|ge|ne|n|s")
    subBeforeSuper := regexp.MustCompile("n|s|sg|ge|ne")
    orderIActuallyWant := regexp.MustCompile("s|sg|ge|ne|n")
    regexes := []*regexp.Regexp{superBeforeSub, subBeforeSuper, orderIActuallyWant}
    for _, rgx := range regexes {
        fmt.Println(rgx.MatchString(str), rgx.FindAllString(str, -1))
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer does not work in the general case; it has the problem I discovered in the comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819437/is-there-a-version-of-rubys-regexp-match-that-responds-to-the-order-of-the-matc) Your regex can't even match "sg" correctly, it splits it into just `s`. That is what I have been TRYING to tell everyone! Whether I put the substrings before or after the superstrings, it doesn't match the whole thing!

Comment: a regex will match in the order of the pattern, so, if you want sg before s, change to `sg|s|ge|ne|n`.

Comment: My understanding is that the rearrangement of the regex is to be done for an arbitrary string, not just for the literal `"sgene"`. EMBLEM, is that correct?